# Undefined function error in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, handwriting-recognition

```
function im = Thresholding(I)
[r,c] = size(I);
im = zeros(r, c);
for i = 1:r
for j = 1:c
    if I(i,j)> 105
        im(i,j) = 1;
    end
end
end
im = bwareopen(im, 5);
im = imfill(im, 'holes');
end
```

I'm trying to use this code and I got this error " Undefined function or method 'bwareopen' for input arguments of type 'double'"please help me

Comment: It seems that the program doesn't recognize it. Are you sure you have the proper version that contains a definition of the function?

Comment: im use matlab R2010b which version that available with that function. i need to finish my final year project for handwriting recognition. im glad if you can hel me. thanks you

Comment: You made an error copying your code here. It contains an invalid character (`).

Comment: @Daniel i've been edit my code. im really a newbie in image processing. can you help me solve this problem of thresholding?

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `bwareopen` but you should be calling [`bwareaopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwareaopen.html). The latter has an extra a.

Comment: i also get this error " Thresholding at 2
[r,c] = size(I);" when i run the above code. can someone help me?

Comment: @user that is the stack where the error occurs, but not the error message.

Comment: Input argument "I" is undefined. this is the error. i can't fix it yet

Comment: You have to call the function with an argument, not just hit the run button.